# Parsing CSV data in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, csv, split

I have a string like this:

`138374:order1,738437:order2,927438:order3`

I am doing a loop to split orders by comma (`,`)

How do I split it further by colon(`:`) to yield the order number and order name.

Below is the code:

```
function(getOrders) {
  var completeOrderRequest = getOrders.split(',');
  for(var j=0; j < orderRequest.split(',').length; j++) {
    alert(completeOrderRequest[j]);
    var nameOrderIds = completeOrderRequest[j].split(':');

    alert("OrderNumber: "+nameOrderIds[0]);
    alert("Name : "+nameOrderIds[1]);
  }  
}
```

Right now its giving me `orderNumber 0`.

Comment: related: [How can I parse a CSV string with Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8493195/how-can-i-parse-a-csv-string-with-javascript), [Javascript code to parse CSV data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293147/javascript-code-to-parse-csv-data)

Answer (score 0):

```
function getOrders( orderString) {
   var orders = orderString.split(','); // create array of ordernumber:name combos
   for( var i=0; i < orders.length; i++) { // use length of above array, not a split again
      var entry = orders[i].split(':'); // now break each combo into it's own array
      alert( "OrderNumber: " + entry[0] );
      alert( "Name: " + entry[1] );
   }
}
```

[demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MDNmF/](http://jsfiddle.net/MDNmF/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that should be more like what you're looking for:

```
function(getOrders) {
  var completeOrderRequest = getOrders.split(',');
  for(var j=0; j < completeOrderRequest.length; j++) {
    var idsAndNames = completeOrderRequest[j].split(':');
    alert("OrderNumber: "+idsAndNames[0]);
    alert("Name : "+idsAndNames[1]);
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is the orderRequest in the orderRequest.split(',') coming from??  should this be instead:

for (var j = 0; j < completeOrderRequest.split(',').length; j++)

If so, that means you are doing a split twice, which would not work because you are splitting on the same character.

Answer (score 0):

what is orderRequest?

```
var getOrders = "138374:order1,738437:order2,927438:order3,";

var completeOrderRequest = getOrders.split(",");

for(i = 0; i < completOrderRequest.length; i++){
   var nameOrderIds = completeOrderRequest[j].split(':');
   alert("OrderNumber: "+nameOrderIds[0]);  
   alert("Name : "+nameOrderIds[1]);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be aware of [var hoisting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174362/javascript-var-hoisting-issue/1175638).  Javascript doesn't have block-scope variables, only function-scope ones; in your code, `nameorderIDs` is actually defined just below `completeOrderRequest`.